# Java exact alternative to getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)

Tags: java, image

I need a method of scaling images that produces the exact same result as getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) but is faster. I already tried messing around with Graphics2D but couldn't get the same result.

Comment: Although not really longer maintained, I made good experience with the [imgscalr](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr) library.

Comment: Did you try the parallel JavaFX/OpenJFX? (Not much hope there though.) It just might be that a power-of-2 scaling followed by a small scaling might be faster with almost same quality: `* 19` as `* 16` fby `* 19.0/16` or such (*32 fby 19.0/32).